# Family Tree in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a family tree program and I'm having troubles deleting a node off of the family tree. I have a `delete` method, which takes the name of the node to delete, finds it, then removes it. I free the `trash` node, the node I'm trying to delete, and set it to `NULL`, but it is still there when I test it. Am I supposed to assign new left and right paths for a node rather than trying to set it to `NULL`?

```
struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*child;


void delete(node* root){
    char array[13];
    node *toDelete;
    printf ("Please specify a name to delete\n");
    scanf("%s", array);
    toDelete = scan(root, array); 
    if(toDelete == NULL) {
            printf("ERROR -- Node does not exist");
    } else {
    removeChild(&toDelete); 
    }
}

void removeChild(node **trash){
    if((*trash)->left == NULL && (*trash)->right == NULL) { //no parents
            free(*trash);
            *trash = NULL;
    }
    else if((*trash)->left == NULL && (*trash)->right != NULL) { //have mother
            removeChild((*trash)->right);
    }
    else if((*trash)->left != NULL && (*trash)->right == NULL) { //have father
            removeChild((*trash)->left);
    } else{  //have both
            removeChild((*trash)->left);
            removeChild((*trash)->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the check for `if (toDelete == NULL)` come before the call to `removeChild`? and shouldn't you only call `removeChild` if `toDelete != NULL` ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Don't clutter it with `scanf` and similar, but make it complete, so people can test it, and add sample input and expected output.

Comment: You never clear the links pointing to the target person, coming from target person's parents. You only clear a local variable: `toDelete`.

Comment: Correct, as for the second post I'll try to construct something

Comment: You may want to double-check the phrasing here: *"I set the ... node I'm trying to delete, to `NULL` and free it"*. If you're indeed doing that *in that order*, then you need to reverse it, i.e. you must first free the node, and then set it to `null`.

Comment: @ray ah yes a typo sorry, just fixed

Comment: @RuudHelderman how/where would I clear those links

Comment: Please be aware that family trees are actually [directed acyclic graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_tree#Graph_theory).

Comment: When you delete a node, you want to delete all it's children (parents), right?

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/379/)

Comment: @antelemon Sorry, I meant to say "coming from target's _children_". As pointed out by others, you still have references to the target person; unless you are willing to store a child list for each person, you'll have to scan the tree in search of target's children.

Comment: @antelemon `struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};` is curious as it has no children.  I'd expect `struct person {
    char *data;
    struct person *father; struct person *mother; struct family *family; }` and `struct family {
    char *data;
    struct person *spouse[2];  struct person **children; }` or the like.

Comment: @chux my bad i forgot to include the child at the end, i have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive calls to `removeChild()` are broken; they should contain a reference to `left`/`right`;  compile should warn about it.  But a more simple implementation would be

```
void removeChild(node **trash) 
{
    if (!*trash)
        return;

    removeChild(&(*trash)->right);    
    removeChild(&(*trash)->left);
    free(*trash);
    *thrash = NULL;
}
```

But the `free()` is probably wrong for your "family tree" where a node can be a parent of multiple children.  You could implement some reference counting here.

The

```
node *toDelete;
...
toDelete = scan(root, array);
...
removeChild(&toDelete);
```

needs to be changed too:  `scan()` should return `node **` so that `&root` can be passed to `removeChild()` (when it matches `array`).

And, "`mother`" and "`father`" might be more suitable names instead of `left` and `right`.

Comment: This is the right answer. You can set it to `NULL` only on the `left / right` pointer itself, not a copy variable, i.e.: `toDelete`. So `toDelete` needs to be a `node **` so that the original pointer can be deleted from the tree by `*toDelete = NULL;`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm trying to fix it, but am ending up with a ton of errors sadly

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Sorry.

Anyways,

```
// free a node and all its children.
// Return # of nodes freed.
int free_node_recursive(node * n){
    int total_freed = 1;

    // free the left child (if any)
    if(n->left != NULL){
        free_node_data(n->left);
        total_freed += free_node_recursive(n->left);
        n->left = NULL;
    }

    // free the right child (if any)
    if(n->right != NULL){
        free_node_data(n->right);
        total_freed += free_node_recursive(n->right);
        n->right = NULL;
    }

    // actually free the thing.
    free(n);

    return total_freed;
}
```

Eg.

```
void delete(node* root){
    char array[13];
    node *toDelete;
    printf ("Please specify a name to delete\n");
    scanf("%s", array);
    toDelete = scan(root, array); 
    if(toDelete == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR -- Node does not exist");
    } else {
        free_node_recursive(&toDelete); 
    }
}
```

Your problem was that, in the global tree (`root`), the reference to the node just deleted would *still be there*. A parser descending the tree would find the reference in the parent still intact, and try to descend into it, finding the data already `free`'d and inaccessible; segfault.

Comment: So obliterate is essentially just a replacement for removeChild right? Confused on removing the reference

Comment: `free` leaves anything that still points to that address intact, so a parser might still descend the tree and try to access the node we just deleted.

Comment: Oh I see your real problem now.

Comment: Yeah so when I print, everything still is outputted. Do I need to unreferenced things somehow?

Comment: so there is a free method replacing the default free method?

Comment: No; I'm using the usual one. Why?

Comment: void free(node **n)

Comment: Did you want `void free(node ** n){` to be `void obliterate(node ** n){`?

Comment: "`free` leaves anything that still points to that address intact" is not quite right.  The contents of the free'd memory are not specified.  The free'd memory is not specified to be intact -it might be - it might not.

Comment: So I'm still having troubles removing the node. The nodes before it are changed to null, but the node I'm trying to delete itself is still intact. Also is `free_node_date` just `free_node`?

Comment: `free_node_data` should free `data`, e.g., `void free_node_data(node *n){free(n->data);}`

Answer (score 1):

Below is my solution:

```
void delete(node* root){
    ......

    node** toDelete;
    toDelete = scan(root, array); 
    if(toDelete == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR -- Node does not exist");
    } else {
        removeChild(*toDelete);
        *toDelete = NULL;
    }
}

void removeChild(struct node *trash){
    if(trash->left != NULL) {
        removeChild(trash->left);
        // no need to write trash->left = NULL here,
        // as the whole subtree would be removed after all done.
    }
    if(trash->right != NULL) {
        removeChild(trash->right);
    }

    free(trash);
}
```

And as a reminder, your `scan` must return a `node**` instead of `node*`.